# Do I need a transit visa if I already have a UK Business visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, transit-visas

I currently have a valid UK and US Business visit Visa (Both are multiple entry visa's). I will be travelling to Portugal next month and my flights are from Mumbai through London to finally Porto. My travel agent was booking a ticket for a flight which will be landing in London heathrow airport and then get on another plane from Gatwick airport (with 5 hrs transit  to get to gatwick)... my question is ...do I need get a transit visa or can I manage with the UK business visa which I already have and have been granted a business visit visa to enter UK.... It would be few hours in London just to get to another airport within London. I will be getting a  Schengen visa to enter Portugal. .

Comment: No need for a transit visa for the UK if you already hold a more senior visa

Comment: Is there  a documentation on any government website to say it.  Just wanted to make sure so that i don't run into a situation with the immigration official.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of _that_ question, exactly.

Comment: @RAVINDRANAVADA Do you have a multientry or a single entry visa?